# Getting data from nest api not working anymore

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, nest-api

I am working with firebase to get data from the nest api. I had a working test setup where I was able to receive data, and set values. Now I am working in python to get a little server running that automatic updates my database. I had data a few days back. But today I wanted to work on it, and i didn't receive any data anymore. So I checked my test setup. And that one is neither getting any data, But I am still able to send data.

This is the javascript I use for my test setup.

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com/');
dataRef.authWithCustomToken("{{user.token}}", function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
    }
});

dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

It should work. But can it be that something broke with the update?

I also created an new client but that did not work either.

An other python application that i am running with nest is using the websocket-client an that one still works. But for the application i am now working on i need to get data from different accounts. If i use the websocket-client it wil use to much resources. so that is not an option.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase upgraded their client recently. Since Nest runs its own instance of Firebase, make sure that you are using one of the supported Firebase versions available here and not that latest version.

https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/firebase-client-libraries